# How do I combine user input with with if statements?

Tags: c++, user-input

I'm making a program. For the program to work, I need to know how to combine user input (cin) with if statements, for example, something like:

```
start:
    (program)    
    cout << "What would you like to do?";
    if cin = "end" goto end;
    if cin = "redo" goto start;

end:
    return 0;
```

I know this isn't valid code, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. I need to know how to do this in C++, if possible, and if not, how to do the same thing.

Also, in Batch, doing something like :start: "bookmarks" the program, so that you can do a "GOTO start" command to jump back to it. How do you do that in C++?

Comment: What source are you learning C++ from?

Comment: `std::string choice; cin >> choice; if(choice == "end") {...}`

Comment: What did you try so far. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: melpomene, I'm learning from youtube videos by "Cave of Programming" and by the cplusplus.com tutorials. 

Mohit Jain, thank you, I will try that, that looks very promising.

 πάντα ῥεῖ , I got stuck right at the point of figuring out the syntax of combining cin with if statements. Mohit Jain's example above seems to be what I wanted, but I'll report back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, everybody. Mohit Jain, that worked, I am so grateful! Syntax was everything. Also, my problem was I had two different strings for two different answers, but Mohit's example made me realize that I only needed just one string for the "choice," not one for restart program and one for end program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a little bit vague, but I'm trying to help you as good as I can.

First of all, the code for reading in a string is:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

(Of course, this requires that you include `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>`).

Secondly, there is support for goto and labels in C++. But in most cases, there are better, more robust and more maintainable solutions to express yourself with. You want to learn more about `while` and `for` loops.

I hope that this answer provides some hints for you, where to start. Any basic C++ book will cover these topics and you should probably get one, if you really want to learn C++ by yourself.

Here is a small example that covers your questions:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main( int, char ** )
{
    std::string input;

    while( true )
    {
        std::cout << "What would you like to do?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;
        if( input == "redo" )
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if( input == "end" )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid input: " << input << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your example earlier. Thank you for your help.